# jQuery DatePicker set time and date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I was asked to modify some code.  We got something like this:

```js
$("#expiration_datepicker").datetimepicker( "option", "disabled", false ).attr('value', '');

$("#expiration_datepicker").datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: '../chassis/images/calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+5Y',
    duration: '',
    <c:if test="${formIsReadonly or form.newsItemId == '-1'}">
        disabled: true,
    </c:if>
    constrainInput: false,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
});
```

Looks like this is setting up the date picker

How Can I set it up to default show todays date and time??
like `dd-m-yy hh:mm`

Comment: It is..its just hacked to hell!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `datepickers` documentation for more customizations. Surely it have..

```js
$("#expiration_datepicker").datetimepicker("option", "disabled", false).attr('value', '');
       
$("#expiration_datepicker").datetimepicker({
    **dateFormat: 'dd-m-yy',** // date format goes here
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: '../chassis/images/calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+5Y',
    duration: '',
    <c:if test="${formIsReadonly or form.newsItemId == '-1'}">
        disabled: true,
    </c:if>
    constrainInput: false,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm'  // time format here
});
```

Usage:

```js
<script>
    $('#expiration_datepicker').click(function() {
        ('#expiration_datepicker').datetimepicker('setDate', (new Date()));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: attr('value', 'PUT THAT FORMAT HERE');`

Comment: attr stands for attribute and here attribute is value so the value of the control will go there ....

Comment: I am able to do something like this `  $("#publication_datepicker").datetimepicker( "option", "disabled", false ).attr('value', $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-m-yy HH:mm', new Date()));`

Comment: but cant put the time in there??

Comment: @AmitRanjan: in this way the datepicker is set with the client date. Is there a way to set it with the server date? e.g. by passing it in some way?

Answer (score 4):

just use setdate and new Date() for date/time right now

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datetimepicker({  
        dateFormat: 'dd-m-yy'        
        // your options
    }).datetimepicker("setDate", new Date());
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d1cqcw4c/)

Comment: @UttamKumarRoy I updated the fiddle for you.  I was importing the files from github and the structure changed so I am now using cdnjs.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add `.datepicker("setDate", "0")` after the `datetimepicker` call. see the code below.

```js
$("#expiration_datepicker").datetimepicker( "option", "disabled", false ).attr('value', ''); 
$("#expiration_datepicker").datetimepicker({  
    dateFormat: 'dd-m-yy hh:mm', // format goes here. Check its documentation for more.         
    showOn: 'button',         
    buttonImage: '../chassis/images/calendar.gif',         
    buttonImageOnly: true,         
    minDate: 0,        
    maxDate: '+5Y',         
    duration: '',         
    <c:if test="${formIsReadonly or form.newsItemId == '-1'}">
        disabled: true,
    </c:if>
    constrainInput: false,         
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
}).datetimepicker("setDate", "0");
```

Answer (score -1):

Set date programmatically:

```js
$('#inputID').datetimepicker("setDate", "05.01.2017 13:36");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question fully, the questioner want to know how to set todays date and time.

Comment: what does this answer add to to the other answers?

Answer (score -1):

```
var d = new Date();
$("#VALUATION_DATETIME").datetimepicker({  
    showSecond: false,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
}).datetimepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

**Output:-** 14/04/2022 17:40