# Incorrect time is selected when user clicks in the textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

When an existing entry for a process phase has a time like 13:53, opening the datetimepicker sets the time automatically to 13:00, so I could by accident change the time without realizing, just by opening the datetimepicker

### Without open datetimepicker

[image: Without open datetimepicker]

### With open datetimepicker

[image: With open datetimepicker]

### problem with datetimepicker

[image: Problem with datetimepicker]

```
function createDateTimePicker(id, timePicker, lang) {

    var displayTimepicker = (timePicker == true ||timePicker == 'true') ;

    var dateTimePicker = $(id).datetimepicker({

        showTimepicker : displayTimepicker,
        controlType: 'select',
        oneLine: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        stepMinute: 5,
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImage: '/assets/images/calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
    return dateTimePicker;
}
```

Is there a way or solution to have the same time as the textfield or the closest time within 5 minutes of the text field time in the datetimepicker?

Comment: Going on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787569/jquery-datepicker-set-time-and-date) `.datetimepicker("setDate", yourDate);` should work

Comment: @umesh, in your code which plugin you're using, jQuery datetimepicker or bootstrap datetimepicker?

Comment: @ankitkanojia, I am using jQuery UI datetimepicker with following documentation https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: @umesh please go through my edited post, i just used you're given plugin, so its work well. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @umesh let me know in case you required any further change. Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();
});

var setDateTime = function() {
  $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker('setDate', (new Date()));
}

var clearDateTime = function() {
  $('#basic_example_1').val('');
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <p>Add a simple datetimepicker to jQuery UI's datepicker</p>

  <div style="display:inline">
    <input type="text" name="basic_example_1" id="basic_example_1" value="" />
    <button onclick="clearDateTime()">clear</button>
    <button onclick="setDateTime()">now</button>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

> I have used jQuery datetimepicker plugin, hope it helps you!!!